# xpath get the third tr and more in a table

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7, xpath, scrapy

I have this html **(just the general case, not the exact html)**

```
<table>
<tr></tr>
<tr></tr>
<tr></tr>
<tr></tr>
</table>
```

how can i get the third tr and more. I mean the third tr, the fourth tr, the fifth tr.... and so on.

#### what I tried

```
table/tr[3:]
```

But I don't know if it is correct or not because the python is not working on my machine right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this XPath:

```
//tr[position() > 2]
```

Comment: +1 Thanks, I will accept the answer after 14 minutes